# How to run object TCL in LINUX Environment?

Tags: linux, tcl

How to run a object TCL script in a LINUX environment? I am working with tcl 8.4. When i am trying to run a below code,

```
package require Itcl
class Tree {
 variable parent ""
}
```

I am getting error "package undefined".

Is it possible to run a object TCl with out a package?

How to check whether the package is installed are not?

can any one help me. Any comments are accepted.

Comment: Is Itcl on your system? `sudo apt-get install itcl3` or `sudo yum install itcl`

Comment: Itcl is not there.. thank you for guiding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the Itcl package onto your system. As you don't say what variety of linux this is we shall guess that it is debian based. `apt-cache search itcl` shows itcl3 and itcl3-dev so it is likely that installing these packages will make this available.

On Debian based systems `dpkg --list packagename` shows if it is installed or not. For instance on my Ubuntu system:

```
$ dpkg --list tcl
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                         Version                      Description
+++-============================-============================-========================================================================
ii  tcl                          8.5.0-2                      The Tool Command Language (default version) - run-time files
```

If you are using some other Linux variety you may need to find the package management utilities for that system or get the sources for Itcl and build it yourself.

Comment: Also, Itcl 4 should ship with Tcl 8.6. Not sure if Debian packages it that way though…